# How to $return value from a controller to be used from other controller

Tags: angularjs

```js
.controller('Search', function($scope) {
  $scope.searchData = {};                                                     
  $scope.searchItem = function($scope) {
    return $scope.searchData.item;
  }
    .controller("SearchMeth", ["$scope", "$firebaseArray", function($scope, $firebaseArray) {
      var cannedRef = new Firebase("https://pricemonitoringsys.firebaseio.com/dti")

      // download the data from a Firebase reference into a (pseudo read-only) array
      // all server changes are applied in realtime
      $scope.cannedGoods = $firebaseArray(cannedRef);

      // create a query for the most recent 25 messages on the server
      //var query = cannedRef.orderByChild('category').equalTo('canned').on("child_added");
       var query = cannedRef.orderByChild("category").equalTo($scope.searchData.search);
      // the $firebaseArray service properly handles database queries as well
      $scope.filteredMessages = $firebaseArray(query);
    }
  ])
})
```

can anyone please help i cant seem to make this code work :( new at this and i have to make this work for my system

Comment: If you want to share this variable between controllers you should use a $rootScope variable or  a Service

Comment: $rootScope is easiest - IMO services should be stateless. you could also use controller inheritance if you want to be funky

Comment: would you please give an example i am new at this stuff

Comment: Do you have something like mainController which is the rootController? If yes, define $scope.searchItem in your mainController, that is, define it globally.

Comment: im using this to be able to accept the input and pass it to a controller to handle the search query i got the search query figured out but i can seem to pass the data to my other controller

Comment: $scope.searchItem = function() {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://pricemonitoringsys.firebaseio.com/dti");
    ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo($scope.searchData.search).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.key() + snapshot.val().category +" "+ snapshot.val().name);
    });
    console.log($scope.searchData.search);
  }

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.
from where is the _searchItem_ is called? html or other controller?

Comment: from Html an ng-model to pass the data

Answer (score 0):

An easy way:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainController">
    <div ng-controller="childController">
        <div ng-controller="Search"></div>
        <div ng-controller="Find"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can just define `$scope.searchItem` in `mainController`, that is, define it globally in the root controller, and then you can use it either in `Search` or other controllers.